Ubuntu 24.04 possible bug
When I'm trying to minimize the applications this green landscape thing pops up and it'll be gone once you full screen the application like a web browser. In my experience it happens on browsers. I only use my laptop for work.


Does it take up about half of the screen? I get an orange one only when I use firefox  full screen, if I move a window around it disappears.

yes I am also getting the orange one, but looks like it's just getting solid color from the applied theme

You should not use the 24.04 release until the version 24.04.1.

@PhilippeGaucher why? It's the upgrade from 22.04 that's not supported until 24.04.1 is released. Why do you think 24.04 shouldn't be used at all?

@ArturMeinild Because last time I installed from scratch a new LTS version (12.04, 14.04 maybe, I don't remember, that was a long time ago), there were unsolved issues and annoying little bugs. So I wait for the 24.04.1. By the way, I always install from scratch, my data are saved on the cloud and in practice on a different SSD. Never tried by updating, maybe I will try next autumn.

Does this answer your question? What is this orange thing taking up half of my screen?

Try turning off Enhanced Tiling in settings under ubuntu desktop.
Also, you can try turning off Ubuntu Tiling Assistant in extensions. Ubuntu Tiling Assistant will be under System Extensions.
Let us know if this solves your problem.
also addressed here
